# add content every 3 posts on Tumblr

Tags: html, themes, tumblr, yahoo

I would like to know if there is a way to put content after 3rd post on every page so I can render something... I don't find anything on tumblr theme API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Specific Post With API

If you are using the API to gather / append posts this would be left for you to do. A simple loop / count should be enough to determine the third post.

#### Specific Post With Themes

If you are creating a Tumblr theme, there is a **theme operator** / **block** to cater for this:

```
{block:Post[1-15]} 
  /* Add something to the post [1-15] on each page */
{/block:Post[1-15]}
```

> Rendered for the post at the specified offset. This makes it possible to insert an advertisement or design element in the middle of your posts.

#### Question Specific Answer

OP states *after* the 3rd post, to do this include the block at the very end of the `{block:Posts}{/block:Posts}` loop.

```
{block:Posts}
  /* All your layout / post logic here, making sure 
     there is nothing left to render */
  {block:Post3}
    /* Add something directly after the third post on each page */
  {/block:Post3}
{/block:Posts}
```

#### Reference

Post Theme Operators: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts

Comment: Is it possible to use the postID to render the posts individually?