# How to replace every 5th article with a div?

Tags: jquery, html, tumblr

I am working on this tumblr theme (http://trollfutbol.tumblr.com/) and I because tumblr generates the posts automatically in articles, to add an ad between some of these I just want to replace every 5th article with the div in which I will add the 300x250 ad.

Html for the parts I am talking about:

```
<div class="content">
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>           Automically generating as many posts as I have.
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
   </div>
   <div class="ad">
   </div>
```

I tried to do this:

```
<script>    
$('article:nth-child(5n)').replaceWith('.ad');
</script>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem with the code you've tried? Do you want to *replace* the fifth article or *insert* an ad after every fifth article?

Comment: You want to replace actual content with an ad? Or you want to insert an ad between the fifth and sixth `<article>` elements?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as the ad ends up in the place where the 5th article is now. But it doesn't seem to happen now... I'll try to use window.load maybe it's because it takes a bit for the articles to load(?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [add content every 3 posts on Tumblr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573814/add-content-every-3-posts-on-tumblr)

Comment: @mikedidthis that works fine if you use a normal tumblr layout of 15 posts (which is the most tumblr can take without any tweaks) but if you use infinite scrolls it generates a million posts so to go manually and add an ad after every 5th post would be impossible as I would have to ad a new add for every five posts I add.

Answer (score 3):

You need to clone the element for appending to multiple elements:

```
$('article:nth-child(5n)').replaceWith($('.ad').clone());
```

**### Working Demo**

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! It still looks strange, but that is easily fixed through css as long as the article clones and adds itself in the place of every 5th article. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I try to apply margin etc now it won't apply it. I tried to inspect the element through Chrome to see what the problem was and it seems to have infinite margin to the right, which can't be removed by adding margin-right: 0; (not even with !important). Any thoughts?

Comment: @RichardLundWinther: i am not good at css. post new question with relevant code and css. someone will surely help you.

Comment: Thankfully I just solved it so no need to do that either, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
$('article:nth-child(5n)').replaceWith('.ad').text();   // remove the term n
or
$('article:nth-child(5n)').replaceWith('.ad').html();   as Bhojendra mentioned
</script>
```

I don't understand why you placed `n` in `nth-child(5n)`. Remove that, it means nothing.

Comment: I added the n because that means I am applying it to every 5th article 5 times n 5th, 10th 15th etc.

Comment: ok, so ad has to appear in every fifth block not just on 5th block

Comment: Exactly. The question has been solved so no need to worry, thanks :)